# set popup widget priority in flex 2.5

Tags: arcgis-server, flex, arcgis-10.0

I have several objects showing but they are ordered in my config.xml file with the highest priority on top. Still when I pick a point object that is near a line object it always gives the popup for the line.
I am learning that it is not the order in the mxd that has anything to do with the order in the web display or the published service,
The order in the config.xml does determine the order of the layers (not the sublayers).
1. What determines the order for object selection/mouse pick when there are more than one poup configured?
2. Has anyone successfully manipulated the order of the layers in the service?

Comment: Brad, Did you ever figure out if it was possible to arrange the order of the popups? I am using Flex 3.7, and I am having this issue as well. If you were able to figure it out I would love to know, if you can share. If not perhaps someone else might answer our questions... In the meantime I am going to continue to work on this and I will let you know what I can come up with.